# BigQuery SQL : Left Join with aggregate conditions

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have two Tables like :
Table1:

```
Time1                          Item1
2021-01-28 18:05:34.647 UTC     ysys-gift-card
2021-01-28 18:06:29.514 UTC     ysys-gift-card
2021-01-28 18:07:36.959 UTC     ysys-gift-card
2021-01-29 04:20:10.916 UTC     sweetheart-flounce-top
2021-01-31 10:20:36.048 UTC     long-sleeve-scallop-mini-dress
2021-02-04 01:04:50.926 UTC     floral-smocked-off-shoulder-top
2021-02-03 07:08:51.386 UTC     a-woven-striped-accents
2021-01-29 22:19:14.359 UTC     mock-neck-lace-bodysuit
2021-01-28 01:41:30.994 UTC     floral-mini-dress
2021-02-03 06:03:45.649 UTC     texture-stud-earring
```

Table2 like:

```
recordID    Time2                             Item2
3121    2021-02-07 12:21:18.808335 UTC  the-zachary-short-circuit
4658    2021-02-07 12:24:23.323713 UTC  pullover-mask-hoodie-1
3420    2021-02-07 12:32:57.886101 UTC  ladies-6-pack-low-cut-socks-1
1190    2021-02-07 12:37:51.026572 UTC  envelope-stitch-crossbody-bag
4151    2021-02-07 12:42:25.424731 UTC  striped-cable-knit-sweater
1651    2021-02-07 12:45:09.691259 UTC  classic-pullover-hoodie
4719    2021-02-07 12:53:25.069348 UTC  rash-vest-color-splash
1314    2021-02-07 12:57:09.828512 UTC  sonia-top-in-mustard-yelllow
1186    2021-02-07 12:59:17.894899 UTC  thermal-heather-sleep-shirt-black-ptlfa020rt-018
3936    2021-02-07 12:59:37.462007 UTC  k2013085blouse
3089    2021-02-07 13:06:16.404185 UTC  product-394
1706    2021-02-07 13:09:07.584634 UTC  ryan-portfolio-dress-shoe-brown-st14028brt-201
1614    2021-02-07 13:10:02.506685 UTC  large-rectangular-metal-sunglasses
4618    2021-02-07 13:23:23.639555 UTC  diamond-quilted-jacket-2
4869    2021-02-07 13:25:50.409423 UTC  princess-panel-polo-dress-2
```

each table several million rows...
So I need to make the left join with conditions:
Item1=Item2
and
time from a second table closest to the time from a first table
Up to 2 minutes and if not then null

In other words, I need to find a record_ID of the same item and the closest time, but no further than 2 minutes ...

So my try like:

```
Select t1.time1, t1.item1
from table 1 t1 left join table2 t2 ON t1.item=t2.item
and
t1.time= ??
```

Here I need help to understand how to write an aggregate condition...
Output like :

```
Time 1                         Item 1                        Record_ID
2021-01-28 18:06:29.514 UTC ysys-gift-card                      3398
2021-01-28 18:07:36.959 UTC ysys-gift-card                      null
2021-01-29 04:20:10.916 UTC sweetheart-flounce-top              2275
2021-01-31 10:20:36.048 UTC long-sleeve-scallop-mini-dress      2307
2021-02-04 01:04:50.926 UTC floral-smocked-off-shoulder-top     null
2021-02-03 07:08:51.386 UTC a-woven-striped-accents             1689
2021-01-29 22:19:14.359 UTC mock-neck-lace-bodysuit             4501
2021-01-28 01:41:30.994 UTC floral-mini-dress                   null
2021-02-03 06:03:45.649 UTC texture-stud-earring                4660
2021-02-04 01:14:08.169 UTC tie-dye-printed-top-and-pants-set   4617
2021-01-28 01:41:30.462 UTC solid-bodycon-mini-dress            null
2021-01-27 11:32:56.490 UTC techno-crepe-stretch                2983
2021-02-04 06:20:18.840 UTC sweater-top-and-mini-skirt-set      1948
2021-02-01 12:36:00.932 UTC floral-race-back-flare-skirt        2932
2021-01-31 06:16:57.916 UTC workout-long-pants                  null
2021-01-29 22:08:06.729 UTC pre-damaged-color-block-tee         2329
```

Thanks

Comment: The "UTC" appended to datetime suggests the column data type is varchar instead of datetime2 or datetimeoffset. If that the case, performance will be bad.

Comment: This Tables with two timestamps (not strings)

Comment: @Galat, that's good. What is the actual column datatype of time1 and time2?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Below should work (BigQuery Standard SQL)!

```
select any_value(t1).*, 
    array_agg(recordID order by abs(timestamp_diff(Time1, Time2, second)) limit 1) recordID
from `project.dataset.table1` t1
join `project.dataset.table2` t2
on Item1 = Item2
group by format('%t', t1)
union all 
select *, null
from `project.dataset.table1`
where not Item1 in (
  select distinct Item2
  from `project.dataset.table2`
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try the following

```
 with table_1 as (
select "2021-01-28 18:05:34.647 UTC" as time1, 'ysys-gift-card' as item1 union all 
select "2021-01-28 18:06:29.514 UTC" as time1, 'ysys-gift-card' union all 
select "2021-01-28 18:07:36.959 UTC" as time1, 'ysys-gift-card' union all 
select "2021-01-29 04:20:10.916 UTC" as time1, 'sweetheart-flounce-top' union all 
select "2021-01-31 10:20:36.048 UTC" as time1, 'long-sleeve-scallop-mini-dress' union all 
select "2021-02-04 01:04:50.926 UTC" as time1, 'floral-smocked-off-shoulder-top' union all 
select "2021-02-03 07:08:51.386 UTC" as time1, 'a-woven-striped-accents' union all 
select "2021-01-29 22:19:14.359 UTC" as time1, 'mock-neck-lace-bodysuit' union all 
select "2021-01-28 01:41:30.994 UTC" as time1, 'floral-mini-dress' union all 
select "2021-02-03 06:03:45.649 UTC" as time1, 'texture-stud-earring'
),
table_2 as (
select 3121 recordId,    "2021-02-07 12:21:18.808335 UTC" as time2,  'the-zachary-short-circuit' as item2 union all
select 4658 recordId,    "2021-02-07 12:24:23.323713 UTC" as time2,  'pullover-mask-hoodie-1' as item2 union all
select 3420 recordId,    "2021-02-07 12:32:57.886101 UTC" as time2,  'ladies-6-pack-low-cut-socks-1' as item2 union all
select 1190 recordId,    "2021-02-07 12:37:51.026572 UTC" as time2,  'envelope-stitch-crossbody-bag' as item2 union all
select 4151 recordId,    "2021-02-07 12:42:25.424731 UTC" as time2,  'striped-cable-knit-sweater' as item2 union all
select 1651 recordId,    "2021-02-07 12:45:09.691259 UTC" as time2,  'classic-pullover-hoodie' as item2 union all
select 4719 recordId,    "2021-02-07 12:53:25.069348 UTC" as time2,  'rash-vest-color-splash' as item2 union all
select 1314 recordId,    "2021-02-07 12:57:09.828512 UTC" as time2,  'sonia-top-in-mustard-yelllow' as item2 union all
select 1186 recordId,    "2021-02-07 12:59:17.894899 UTC" as time2,  'thermal-heather-sleep-shirt-black-ptlfa020rt-018' as item2 union all
select 3936 recordId,    "2021-02-07 12:59:37.462007 UTC" as time2,  'k2013085blouse' as item2 union all
select 3089 recordId,    "2021-02-07 13:06:16.404185 UTC" as time2,  'product-394' as item2 union all
select 1706 recordId,    "2021-02-07 13:09:07.584634 UTC" as time2,  'ryan-portfolio-dress-shoe-brown-st14028brt-201' as item2 union all
select 1614 recordId,    "2021-02-07 13:10:02.506685 UTC" as time2,  'large-rectangular-metal-sunglasses' as item2 union all
select 4618 recordId,    "2021-02-07 13:23:23.639555 UTC" as time2,  'diamond-quilted-jacket-2' as item2 union all
select 4869 recordId,    "2021-02-07 13:25:50.409423 UTC" as time2,  'princess-panel-polo-dress-2' as item2 
)

Select t1.time1, t1.item1, t2.recordId
from table_1 t1 
left join table_2 t2 
 ON t1.item1=t2.item2
and timestamp(t1.time1) between timestamp(t2.time2) and timestamp_add(timestamp(t2.time2), interval 2 minute)
```

Comment: timestamp(t1.time1) between timestamp(t2.time2) and timestamp_add(timestamp(t2.time2), interval 2 minute). Thanks Daniel Zagales, but if there is more than one row that meets the conditions, then need the closest by time...